# How To Handle Re-Created Directories In A Subversion Working Copy?

Tags: svn

Scenario: a User deletes a directory from a SVN Working Copy and afterwards she creates a new directory in the WC at the same location and using the same name. So, before we had a directory including svn information and now we have a directory with the same name w/o svn information.

Can subversion handle this? How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "new" folder (just cut it and paste it in a new folder outside your WC. Then do an update on the whole folder and the original folder will return. Then you can cut and paste the contents of your "new" folder into the original folder and add them and check them in as normal.

Answer (score 2):

`svn update deletedFolder --force` will bring it back and merge in any changes that exist in the local version of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to submit the deleted state to repository. After that you can create a new directory with the same name and subversion will get it as new.